# Permission denied error on CSV export Laravel

Tags: csv, laravel, laravel-4, permission-denied

I am using Laravel 4. When I try to export a database table to CSV file I get this error,

```
fopen(file.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

This is my code,

```
public function getExport(){

    $table = Users::all();

    $filename = "file.csv";
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    fputcsv($handle, array('name', 'status'));

    foreach($table as $row) {
        fputcsv($handle, array($row['name'], $row['status']));
    }

    fclose($handle);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    );

    return Response::download($filename, 'tweets.csv', $headers);
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

The `file.csv` is created inside the current working directory. Which is the root directory that don't have the write permission. To fix this permission I give write permission to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this `chmod 777 file.csv` on your terminal and run your php again

Comment: The file.csv created at the time of importing